# Как размонтировать каталог файловой системы в Debian?

Tags: debian, mount

Периодически нужно с виндового сервера на линуксовый забирать содержимое определенной директории.

Единоразово получается это сделать следующей командой:

```
mount -t cifs -o username=name,password=password //192.168.1.1/\directory$/ /var/www/public/directory
```

но при повторном ее выполнении пишет ошибку: "mount error(16): Device or resource busy", это понятно, ведь каталог уже примонтирован.

Получается, чтобы снова забрать данные, нужно размонтировать ее, и снова этой командой примонтировать.

Почитав маны, и попробовав несколько вариантов, например:

```
umount /var/www/public/directory
```

у меня ничего не вышло:

```
umount: /var/www/public/directory: target is busy
```

Как правильно размонтировать данную директорию?

Получилось командой

```
umount -t cifs /var/www/public/directory
```

Comment: Опция `-t` у `umount` не должна ни на что влиять. Очевидно, к моменту успешного отмонтирования просто какой-то процесс перестал пользоваться этой файловой системой

Comment: Скажите, а почему после umount когда снова делаю mount, данные не забираются? Может что-то рестартовать нужно?

Answer (score 0):

CIFS как и NFS очень зависят от настроек прав на стороне сервера.

Если возникают зависания при размонтирование в большинстве случаев помогает рестарт клиентской машины.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего какой-то процесс использует папку или файл.

`fuser` или `lsof` надо смотреть. Чаще всего поможет `cd /` или закрытие `mc`.